# Craft 3 Feed-Me Auto run all feed

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I currently use `Feed-Me` to pull data from an API-Endpoint. This API-Endpoint does change from time to time, providing new elements with each change.

I don't want to manually trigger the Feed-Me-Reimport each time I notice a change.
I do know that Feed-Me provides actions URLs for each `feed-entry` but as the amount of different import-feeds will grow rapidly soon, I don't think it's feasable to manually create those feeds, and after creation also manually put the URL into a custom cronjob.

So in the end what I'd like to have is simply a script that is triggered by a single cronjob, then gets all Feed-Me feeds and for each feed run the reimport.

Via [PluginFactory](https://pluginfactory.io/) I already generated a plugin that provides me an endpoint(/controller) to be called by `cron`

```
public function actionAutoImport()
    {
        $result = 'Autoimport engaged';

        return $result;
    }
```

But now I am wondering: How do I get information from the Feed-Me plugin i.e. get all existing feeds and trigger a run on each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
use Craft;
use verbb\feedme\FeedMe;
use verbb\feedme\queue\jobs\FeedImport;

$feeds = FeedMe::$plugin->feeds->getFeeds();

foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    $limit = null;
    $offset = null;
    $processedElementIds = [];

    Craft::$app->getQueue()->delay(0)->push(new FeedImport([
        'feed' => $feed,
        'limit' => $limit,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'processedElementIds' => $processedElementIds,
    ]));
}
```

The above will add all your feeds to Craft's queue system and start them.

Comment: can you pass a url to the feed using this method? I'm currently using a pretty hacky way to trigger a feed programatically -> https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/trigger-feedme-import-from-plugin/32955#32955

Comment: Small update for newer versions of the Feedme plugin:
`$feeds = \craft\feedme\Plugin::$plugin->getFeeds()->getFeeds();`

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning now that for more recent versions of FeedMe, the console command natively supports an all flag.

https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/trigger-import-via-cron.html#console-command