# Trigger FeedMe import from plugin

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-feedme, modules

I'm importing Real Estate properties every 30 minutes into my website.
I have a controller action that triggers this but the import is extremely slow and blocks the entire site.

Right now I'm triggering the imports with this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Where the url is the cron url of the feed.

Comment: What's the reason you don't point the cron job directly at the FeedMe url?

Comment: Because I first need to generate the json file before I can import it. It's a dynamic thing.

Comment: Hey, I've had to do this today so have updated my answer with the solution I have: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/32955/526

Answer (score 1):

FeedMe shows you what the import trigger endpoint that you can use with curl in the feed configuration.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now but my controller action seems to handle the import synchronous and waits for it to end.

Answer (score 1):

One potential way is to trigger curl from your plugin with `exec`:

```
// Set the feed me URL
$url =  'http://your.domain/actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task?direct=1&feedId=1&passkey=FwafY5kg3c'

// Build the curl command with the url
$cmd = 'curl --silent --compressed "'.$url.'"';

// Execute the command in the background
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

That should then run the task using another process.

You will likely need to enable `exec()` function on your environment.

Even better if you use a daemon to process your queue with a `nice` command (if not [have a look here](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms)) it will run as a low priority task and slow your front-end down less.